# Opening Other link in other browser android Webview

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I am facing a problem when trying to overrideurl 
i used this code in my webviewclient

```
 mywebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().contains("google") || Uri.parse(url).getHost().contains("goo.gl") ) {
                return false;
            }


            Intent  intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            return true ;
        }

    });
```

Then links containg the above strings are opened in the webview itself but other link like facebook and all are not be able to open in either external browser , while Youtube link is opening in Youtube app.
And how to open facebook links in facebook app or market links in there native app.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is **Chrome Custom Tabs**.

Here's a tip to *create* one.

1.add *dependency*

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:23.4.0'
}
```

2. Create and load your Url

`Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://example.com");`

```
CustomTabsIntent.Builder intentBuilder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();

// Begin customizing
// set toolbar colors
intentBuilder.setToolbarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary));
intentBuilder.setSecondaryToolbarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimaryDark));

// set start and exit animations
intentBuilder.setStartAnimations(this, R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
intentBuilder.setExitAnimations(this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left,
        android.R.anim.slide_out_right);

// build custom tabs intent
CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = intentBuilder.build();

// launch the url
customTabsIntent.launchUrl(activity, uri);
```

Refer to [Here](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs) for more information.

Comment: No I don't want custom tabs what i want is to only open a particular website inside webview and if that site has link to other markets like a playstore link it should open playstore directly